# How can i have Swift Playgrounds 4.1 in macOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, applications, install

I'm on macOS Monterey, I can't use Swift Playgrounds from the store on it because the store version requires macOS Ventura. How can I get the Monterey compatible version?

Answer (score 1):

The application depends on system frameworks and is not stand alone. You will need to virtualize the newer OS on top of your older one and take the speed penalty. It might not even be an issue once you get going on your development.

Also, don't discount how well that app works on iPad / iOS - if you're just in it to learn - you might do that faster and less expensively if your Mac can't run the new OS.

Comment: I understand, so it means that I will need to use a virtual machine to use it ??

Comment: Yes - you need a different platform or to virtualize the newer macOS as a guest on your older macOS host. Getting a VM to work with the App Store can be tricky - so you'll want to ask a new question once you've tried and failed on your first shot to virtualize (if it fails of course - and if you make it work, feel free to ask a "question" where you self answer and help others with your working solution)

Comment: man, perfect! I had an idea to solve this! Will I use a virtual machine or a clean install! I'll see what I think is best for this, but you explained it to me... Thank you very much! If I make it, I'll be back!